# I am using UITextView on a scroll view ...and I want it to auto expand when I write something in it ......

Tags: iphone

```
textViewBusiness = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,332,268,60)];
textViewBusiness.text=strMyBusiness;
textViewBusiness.editable=NO;
textViewBusiness.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0];
textViewBusiness.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textViewBusiness.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
textViewBusiness.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[textViewBusiness setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.scrollView addSubview: textViewBusiness];

CGRect frame = textViewBusiness.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewBusiness.contentSize.height;
textViewBusiness.frame = frame;
```

with the increase in contents i want to increase the size of text field....

This code is not working for me ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide your code into 2 fragments, then place them into proper places, then your code should work.

Fragment 1 (in my test, I place this fragment in viewDidLoad):

```
textViewBusiness = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,332,268,60)];
textViewBusiness.text=strMyBusiness;
textViewBusiness.editable=NO;
textViewBusiness.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0];
textViewBusiness.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
textViewBusiness.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
textViewBusiness.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[textViewBusiness setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.scrollView addSubview: textViewBusiness];
```

Ensure that the above fragment run, and your text view is displayed in the screen, then run the second fragment. If your text view is not displayed in the screen, then the contentView is not initialized, and the height is undefined.

Fragment 2 (in my test, I place this fragment in `viewDidAppear`):

```
CGRect frame = textViewBusiness.frame;
frame.size.height = textViewBusiness.contentSize.height;
textViewBusiness.frame = frame;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to take `UITextView` for showing un-editable text. Besides this you can use UILabel and you can find out the height of label at run time. Each time the content vary in size set frame of `UILabel` accordingly.

Use this to find out height of your label at run time

```
- (CGFloat) heightOfTextLabel:(NSString *) contentText
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(268,4000);

    CGSize size = [contentText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

     return size.height;       
}
```

This method would return you a variable height of the content each time.

Now set this height to your `UILabel`

```
CGFloat heightOfLabel = [self heightOfTextLabel:strMyBusiness];

UILabel* textToShowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,332,268,heightOfLabel)];

textToShowLabel.text=strMyBusiness;

textToShowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 17.0];

textToShowLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

textToShowLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

textToShowLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[textToShowLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[self.scrollView addSubview: textToShowLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

`GrowingTextView` is a reusable iOS compenent that does exactly what you need, you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView) .

I hope this helps.